# Extract first element in the class using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This 
[search](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=Zck&channel=fs&ei=DwVuXaKGO832rQG6xLO4DQ&q=new+york+pincode&oq=new+york+pincode&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30l5.8789.13949..14325...4.2..0.136.1771.4j12......0....1..gws-wiz.....10..0i71j35i39j0i67j0i131j0i131i20i263j0i20i263j0i22i10i30.0omoHBJAff0&ved=0ahUKEwjiyfulgLTkAhVNeysKHTriDNcQ4dUDCAo&uact=5)
gives the result and there are multiple pincodes present. I only need to capture the first element in the class.

code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
import html5lib
import json
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
url = "https://www.google.com/"
chromedriver = r"C:\Users\me\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("newyork pincode")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) 



time.sleep(5) 
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Finding the class with the name `h998We mlo-c` and getting the first element will give you the first pin code.

Comment: would the class name change for other pincodes

Comment: @thoris answer updated wit a bit explanation, hope helps more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `css selector` or `xpath` to achieve.

- Css Selector ***recommended**

  ```
  div.IAznY div.title
  ```
- Xpath

  ```
  //div[@class="IAznY"]//div[@class="title"]
  ```

Add `WebDriverWait` instead `time.sleep(..)` for effeciency.

First you need following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```

***note***: `find_element_by_*` always return the first element, even if there are many elements with the same locator.

So you can use the bellow code:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("newyork pincode")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.IAznY div.title')))
print(element.text)
```

But if you need handle `multiple` like you say and you want not the first element, then you can use `.find_elements_by_*`. The code below is an example to get the second element:

```
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.IAznY div.title')))
print(elements[1].text)
```

This is index `[1]`, and you can see the difference between the first code and the second code in the `WebDriverWait` implementation, namely `visibility_of_element_located` and`visibility_of_all_elements_located`

Comment: If you just want the first element, there's no reason to use `.find_elements_*()`, just use `.find_element_*()`. Also, the `WebDriverWait()` statement above returns the waited for element. By waiting and then doing another find elements, you are hitting the page twice. I've edited your answer to show you the streamlined way to do this.

Comment: I would argue (and it has been proven) that CSS selectors are faster than XPath. Given this locator doesn't require XPath, you can easily convert it to `div.IAznY div.title`, which is also much shorter and more readable (I think). I'll let you edit that in, if you want, because I feel it deviates too much from your intended answer for me to do.

Comment: Thanks very much, agree what you have done, very clear for me. You are one of the best stackoverflow users in the selenium class.

Answer (score 0):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and Following Css Selector to identify the element.

```
elements=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.mlo-c div.title')))
print(elements[0].text)
```

**Printed on console:**

```
 10001
```

You need to import followings to execute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score -1):

Finding the class with the name `h998We mlo-c` and getting the first element will give you the first pin code.

`find_element_by_class_name('h998We mlo-c')` and it will return you all the pin codes for any city such as Delhi which you were asking earlier, and then get the text inside the `div` to get the `Pincode`

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_class_name

Comment: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".h998We mlo-c"}

Comment: `find_element_by_class_name()` expects a single class name and you are sending it two. This will cause an error.

Comment: Got it let me rewrite my solution.